# Overpass API results in empty map

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am wondering why this API request gives an empty map:

https://overpass-api.de/api/map?bbox=-0.7438,50.8940,0.4810,52.1190

If I use a smaller bbox it seems giving back a map.I could not find any maximum width or length of the bbox in the API documentation.

I found this error in the empty map file.

Is there any way to overcome this RAM issue?

runtime error: Query ran out of memory in "recurse" at line 1. It would need at least 540 MB of RAM to continue.

Answer (score 3):

This /map query triggers a download of 3.6GB worth of XML data, and the memory needed to process such a request exceeds the permitted memory limit for /map queries.

Either choose a smaller bounding box and try again, or if you need really large areas, use one of the available OSM extracts instead: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts